# Start new application instance instead of continuing a suspended one

Tags: zsh

If i for example start `top`. suspend it with `Ctrl+Z`, then enter `top` again the previously started instance will be continued in the foreground. How can i avoid this behaviour and just start a new instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to unset the option [AUTO_RESUME](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fRESUME):

> AUTO_RESUME (-W)
>
> Treat single word simple commands without redirection 
>   as candidates for resumption of an existing job.

Comment: Thank you. Thought there might be a command but this is perfect.

Comment: To start a new instance just this time, arrange for some part of the command name to be quoted, e.g. `\top` or `=top`.

Comment: @Gilles: Works as well, why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Why not just press 'q' in top to exit, instead of ctrl-z?   Strange.